# rails not sending mails on local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailer

i can't make my mailer work on development environment.
This is my configuration on development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port: 587,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'user@email.com,
  password: 'mypassword,
  authentication: 'login',
  domain: 'mandrill.com'
}
```

My mailer method:

```
class InformationRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def information_request(operator, ref, property_url, contact_info)
    @operator = operator
    @property_url = property_url
    mail(to: operator.email, subject: t("information_request_mailer.subject", property_ref: ref))
  end
end
```

And here I'm calling it:

```
InformationRequestMailer.delay.information_request(
    operator: operator,
    ref: ref,
    property_url: property_url,
    contact_info: params[:contact_info]
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors in the logs? I'm also going to assume you have the closing `'` in the password field for the configuration.

Comment: What OS dev env is running on? Does it have `sendmail` or like installed?

Comment: I get no error at all, @JustinWood. And yes, password has the correspondent closing '. I'll fix that here..

Comment: Good call @mudasobwa. How do i check if i have sendmail? Im on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @ntonnelier E.g. by opening a console and trying to send an email directly from there. `man sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a current `Rails` version, this should work:

```
InformationRequestMailer.information_request(
  operator: operator,
  ref: ref,
  property_url: property_url,
  contact_info: params[:contact_info]
).deliver_later
```

And since you want to use the delayed delivery, you need to have you queue workers running.

Comment: thanks @Yury but it doesnt take the method that way. Should be the way i described above. Im using rails 4.1.1

Comment: No @Yury, it does not.

Comment: Can you try to add `.deliver` here: `mail(...).deliver`?